# trying to use a script variable in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jinja2

I am trying to set the default value of an input in html with one that I get in the json from my ajax update function.  The value is getting back from the ajax correctly, but I am having a devil of a time using it in the html.

I have created a "namespace" to contain my variables.  How do I use the variables in my html?  Note that ".innerHTML" and ".value" don't work because (I'm guessing) this is an input with min, max, step?  If I replace {{ myNamespace.low_pump_speed_value }} with an acceptable number (between 800 and 1500), the code works as expected.

I am getting the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'myNamespace' is undefined
```

Here is the html file:

```
<body>
    <script>
        myNamespace = { low_pump_speed_value: 850,
                        high_pump_speed_value: 950,
                        chlorine_percent_value: 1050};
        document.write(myNamespace)
        console.log("second", myNamespace)
    </script>

    <label for="low-pump-speed-id">Low Pump Speed:</label>
    <input type="number" id="low-pump-speed-id" name="low-pump-speed-id" step="50" min="800" max="1500" required value="{{ myNamespace.low_pump_speed_value }}">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){$.ajax({
        url: '/update',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            myNamespace.low_pump_speed_value = response["pump"]['low-speed'];
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })}, 250);
</script>
```

Comment: To make `myNamespace` global .. Use `window.`  --  IE `window.myNamespace = { low ...`  -- And every time you use it ..  `window.myNamespace.low_pump_speed_value =`

Comment: tried moving myNamespace to window.myNamespace, but I get jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'window' is undefined

Comment: My problem is not setting the namespace value.  My problem is using the value once its set

Answer (score 1):

You should use values within the max..min range, for example:

```
myNamespace = { low_pump_speed_value: 900,
```

Then, you can assign this value to the input field as follows:

```
var inputField = document.getElementById("low-pump-speed-id");
inputField.value = myNamespace.low_pump_speed_value;
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, .value does not work.  You are correct about the values (I changed my question), but it does not work even when the values are within the min and max.

Comment: I spoke too soon!  Your solution works as you suggested

Comment: I have another question: how can I update myNamespace from the ajax call?  I can't seem to be able to change it (that is, I can change it, but it is never used - the html always gets the original value

Comment: I am doing this:             success: function(response) {
                document.myNamespace = { low_pump_speed_value: response["pump"]['low-speed'],
                                         high_pump_speed_value: response["pump"]['high-speed'],
                                         chlorine_percent_value: response["chlorinator"]['chlorine-percent']}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks (bedankt) to [www.admiraalit.nl](http://www.admiraalit.nl), this is now working:
I have to believe that it was something stoopid I was doing as I thought I started out this way and just wound up in the weeds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('override_select') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href={{ url_for('static',filename='favicon.png') }} />
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/root.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="low-pump-speed-id">Low Pump Speed:</label>
        <input type="number" id="low-pump-speed-id" name="low-pump-speed-id" step="50" min="800" max="1500">
        <label for="high-pump-speed-id">High Pump Speed:</label>
        <input type="number" id="high-pump-speed-id" name="high-pump-speed-id" step="50" min="800" max="1500">
        <label for="chlorine-percent-id">Chlorine Percent:</label>
        <input type="number" id="chlorine-percent-id" name="chlorine-percent-id" step="50" min="800" max="1500">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function(){$.ajax({
            url: '/update',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                document.getElementById("low-pump-speed-id").value = response["pump"]['low-speed'];
                document.getElementById("high-pump-speed-id").value =response["pump"]['high-speed'];
                document.getElementById("chlorine-percent-id").value = response["chlorinator"]['chlorine-percent'];
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })}, 2000);
    </script>
</form>
```